# Under load, the following job-queue design does not work reliably, why?

Tags: mysql

I have a job queue table which is meant to mark-and-return one job at a time to the caller. The stored procedure works like this:

```
update job_queue
set status = "WORKING", job_id = <arg_unique_job_id>
where status = "NEW"
limit 1
;

if row_count() > 0 then

    select
        -- get job details for work
    from job_queue
    where job_id = <arg_unique_job_id>
    ;

else

    -- nothing to do
    select 1 from dual where false;

end if;
```

The client generates a unique number (arg_unique_job_id) and passes it to the stored procedure. If there is any work to be done, that work will be marked as "WORKING" and get assigned the caller's job ID.

On occasion, under heavy DB load, I would find a job marked as WORKING but the client did not appear to get any row back, as if `row_count` "lied". Above statements are executed in one transaction, against InnoDB table (MySQL 5.6.39). Am I wrong in my assumption how above should work, or the error is likely elsewhere?

Comment: How many rows in `job_queue`?  Do you delete finished tasks?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  How frequently are items added to the queue?  How long does the average item take to process?

Comment: Jobs take sub-second to execute. There is an alarm whenever/if jobs were to take more than 3 std dev. The alarm works. There is about 50 jobs per second. The job_queue table has 4 columns, client_submission_id, status, timestamp and the job_id. Primary key is client_submission_id. there is a key (job_id) to quickly retrieve the updated row. There is about 150,000 jobs in the table - oldest, completed jobs are purged periodically.

Answer (score 1):

In similar situation I use:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN END;

REPEAT

    UPDATE job_queue
    SET status = "WORKING", job_id = <arg_unique_job_id>
    WHERE status = "NEW"
    LIMIT 1;

    SELECT *
    FROM job_queue
    WHERE job_id = <arg_unique_job_id>;

UNTIL row_count() < 1 END REPEAT;
```

It's never gone wrong before.

PS. This construction was used in the case when a record free for reservation exists with guarantee. If not use some local variable (some @loopcount) for to limit the max amount of cycles to avoid infinite loop.

Comment: I have rewrote my code to not rely on row_count(), just always select whatever UPDATE changed and deal with the results in the client. All previous problems got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

"Don't queue it, just do it".

The overhead of the queuing mechanism threatens to dominate the work expended.

And, when there is a hiccup, the queuing mechanism can become the bottleneck.

`status` seems redundant; `job_id IS NULL` could be the clue of being "NEW".  (A `UNIQUE` key treats `NULLs` as being different.)

Comment: Jobs may fail for various reasons, hence the status column. Queuing is a safety measure to ensure that if there is a backend processing problem, the queue will grow but the backend will have time to catch up. The code is not written for the average case, but for fault tolerance.

Comment: If this queue table is forever growing, _that_ could be part of the problem.

Comment: entries expire in the queue table, about 150k right now. It's "nothing".

Comment: I'm going to redesign the code so it does not rely on row_count() and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Slawomir - A "table scan" of 150K rows is not "nothing".  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and _all_ the queries that touch the table to see if it has good indexes.

Comment: @Slawomir - Yes.  One `SELECT` would serve the intent of both `SELECTs` without the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the logic such that the SELECT is run unconditionally, ie I got rid of the `row_count() > 0` check and handle results in the client. The problem went away.